# Subset dataframe by partially matching rownames

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame of multiple rows (gene names) and columns (TCGA barcodes). I would like to subset multiples rows by name (not exact name necessarily) at the same time, with all columns.

When I extract one gene I use this code, for example: `ind_keep2 <- grep('^SEPT1$',rownames(z_rna))`

My problem is that I dont know how to extract multiples rows (genes). For example, SEPT1, TP53...

```
# example data
# dput(head(z_rna[, 1:3]))

z_rna <- structure(list(TCGA.P7.A5NX = c(0.1711, 0.4333, 0.1708, 0.3339, -0.1942, -0.4844), TCGA.P7.A5NY = c(0.0299, 0.3991, 0.2363, -0.0664, -0.0966, -0.4842), TCGA.P8.A5KC = c(-0.3365, 0.4123, 0.2312, -0.0725, 0.0562, -0.4854)), row.names = c("RBL2_cg00000029", "VDAC3_cg00000236", "ACTN1_cg00000289", "ATP2A1_cg00000292", "SFRP1_cg00000321", "NIPA2_cg00000622"), class = "data.frame")


                  TCGA.P7.A5NX TCGA.P7.A5NY TCGA.P8.A5KC
RBL2_cg00000029         0.1711       0.0299      -0.3365
VDAC3_cg00000236        0.4333       0.3991       0.4123
ACTN1_cg00000289        0.1708       0.2363       0.2312
ATP2A1_cg00000292       0.3339      -0.0664      -0.0725
SFRP1_cg00000321       -0.1942      -0.0966       0.0562
NIPA2_cg00000622       -0.4844      -0.4842      -0.4854
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove *ProbeIDs*, everything after `"_"` from rownames, and compare with our genes:

```
# subset using GeneIDs:
myGenes <- c("RBL2", "NIPA2")

z_rna[ gsub("\\_.*", "", rownames(z_rna)) %in% myGenes, ]
#                  TCGA.P7.A5NX TCGA.P7.A5NY TCGA.P8.A5KC
# RBL2_cg00000029        0.1711       0.0299      -0.3365
# NIPA2_cg00000622      -0.4844      -0.4842      -0.4854
```

To subset using ProbeIDs, remove GeneIDs:

```
# subset using ProbeIDs
myProbeIDs <- c("cg00000029", "cg00000622")
z_rna[ gsub(".*\\_", "", rownames(z_rna)) %in% myProbeIDs, ]
#                  TCGA.P7.A5NX TCGA.P7.A5NY TCGA.P8.A5KC
# RBL2_cg00000029        0.1711       0.0299      -0.3365
# NIPA2_cg00000622      -0.4844      -0.4842      -0.4854
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? `grepl` looks for the pattern, the `,` at the end makes sure that all columns are selected, and that the subset is made on the rows.

```
z_rna[grepl(pattern = "^SEPT1$", rownames(z_rna)),]
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me: invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment